# JavaScript check if value is superior and respect multiples

Tags: javascript

I have some trouble on how I should implement a check value :

I have an input which user can increments. When this input reaches every multiple of 100 (100,200,300,400.....) it updates a count displayed on the screen.

My original code was :

```
if(Number.isInteger(actualValue/100)){
                        input.base += 1;
        }
```

The problem is that now the user increments by 1 or 2 or 3 etc... With this actual code if I'm at 99 and I increment by 2, it'll not update input.

How can I check if the value equals or is above a multiple of 100?

He can also decrements so I must do the reverse operation and update input to -1.

I don't know where to go. Any advices would be welcome!

EDIT :

A quick JSfiddle to let you know what is happening : https://jsfiddle.net/4h1u6d2x/

Try to go to 10 then you can try to go from 19 to 21 and see that this is not updated!

Comment: Please share a [mcve] with us!

Comment: Can you show anymore code?  Such as how the user increments/decrements said input?  Hard to wrap your head around the code without seeing user interaction, especially in this example.

Comment: You can have a variable that acts as a checkpoint whenever you reach a multiple of 100, and check if this input value is a multiple of 100 *that is larger than the one you already had*.

Comment: I edited my post to add a little JSfiddle I have done quickly to show you!

Answer (score 1):

If the value is only dependent of `actualValue`, you could take the integer value.

```
input.base = Math.floor(actualValue / 100);
```

Comment: This is a good idea thanks but in fact the value I'm incrementing after is also dependant of other things...

Answer (score 1):

I am not for sure where that 99 is coming from but you could technically loop through the incremented/decremented amount, add or subtract from the 99 (assuming that is a running total that is being saved somewhere) you mentioned, and check to see if the return value AT ANY POINT is evenly divisible by 100.

Something like this.

let user_input = 8
var input = 0;

```
for (let i = 0; i < user_input; i++){
    let sum = i + 93;
    if (sum % 100 === 0){
        input++
        break
    }
}
```

console.log(input)

That way, you are checking every possible sum/difference, regardless of how many times the user increases or decreases their input.

Comment: This could be 99 or 98 or 97 or 91 whatever, user can choose his increment

Comment: With a little tweaking, because I can't see all your code, this should suffice.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing and what you actually want to achieve seem like they are different.

If you want to just have a count of how many times the actual value is bigger than `gap` then you can do what Nina said:

```
input.base = Math.floor(actualValue / 100);
```

If on the other hand, you want to increment the base reactively you should hold the previous state. You can also implement the decrement this way.

```
let changeIndex = 0;

if (changeIndex <= actualValue + gap) {
  changeIndex += gap;
  input.base += 1;
}

if (changeIndex > actualValue) {
  changeIndex -= gap;
  input.base -= 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Since the value is based on other things I can't only rely on the integer given by the gap. Also, I can't neither hold the previous state because this function will be used by many different inputs. I'm sorry for not being clear.

Comment: @ZeyukanIch' If you could tell me what things it is based on, or post a bit of your code that does this maybe I would be more able to help